# GWT DataGrid change row font-size

Tags: css, gwt, datagrid, font-size

I have a DataGrid created. Now I want user to be able to click on buttons with + and - signs, to make the text in data grid larger, or smaller.

I know I can do something like:

```
DataGrid table = new DataGrid<Row>();
table.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<LogRow>() {
    @Override
    public String getStyleNames(LogRow row, int rowIndex) {
      return className;
    }
});
```

But I want to change the font dynamically. I mean "current font size + 1" or "current font size - 1".

Is there a way? Or do I have to create special class for each font-size?

I tried defining a constant in GSS that takes it's value from a "getFontSize()" method of my class, but it is a CONSTANT, so it will only get that value once, and then ignores any changes to fontSize property in my class.

I tried

```
table.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(newFontSize, Style.Unit.PX);
```

or

```
table.getRowContainer().getStyle().setFontSize(newFontSize, Style.Unit.PX);
```

but with no success. Maybe I have to target child elements?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`@eval`](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Runtime_substitution) in your stylesheet. maybe this snippet can help you

```
//refer to a method, that returns a string for your front size.
//your can change the return value of getFontSize() at any time
@eval FONT_SIZE com.your.app.client.css.getFontSize();
@external .fontSize;
.fontSize{
    font-size: FONT_SIZE;
}
```

then inject your style, and replace it when you want to change the font-size:

```
public class Css {
    public static String FONT_SIZE= "18px";

    public static String getFontSize() {
         return FONT_SIZE;
    }

    public Css(){
        CssResource res = GWT.create(YourRes.class);
        StyleElement styleElement = StyleInjector.injectStylesheet(res.getText());
        FONT_SIZE = "25px";
        StyleInjector.setContents(styleElement , res.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using GSS, so the syntax is a little different, but it seems like what I want. I did the @def FONT_SIZE eval("package.function()"); I just didn't know how to "reeval" this. So I guess your code solves this, however it seems to override my styles (from bootstrap) and completely messes up my UI and the font size is not changing. As soon as I get it to work I accept your answer :)

Comment: Ok I can inject my gss file, I see the font size changes in it. However the original style has classname: ".C2PGHCB-f-q td", but the injected has classname ".C2PGHCB-a-q td", so it deos not override the previous style as it has different name.

Comment: ohh i just checked my example again... you have to add the css class, that uses the `@eval FONT_SIZ`, to `@external`...create the class `.fontSIze` and add this to your gridRows. so only this `.fontSize` wont be obfuscated.i will edit my post

Comment: That was it!! Thank you! Didn't know about @external